# Chrome extension load a background.js each time the page reloads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can I reload the `background.js` each time a page reloads with my chrome extension?

I want to use it to inject a CSS file each time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`background.html` - The [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html), is only loaded once for each chrome session.
*(I assumed that your `background.js` file runs from a background page, because of the file name)*

- If you want to execute Javascript for each page, you have to use [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).
- If you want to inject static CSS in every page, have a look at this Stack Overflow question:

  - [Inject CSS into webpage — developing chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7619095/938089?inject-css-into-webpage-developing-chrome-extension)