# Execute js to change CSS in background - Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am designing a Chrome plugin. I have a script that injects CSS into a web page. It is linked to the popup.html for now, because it only works like that.

The problem is, I have to click on the icon to open the popup before the css is injected. Because that loads the javascript file to inject the CSS. I don't want to have to do that.

Oh, content scripts aren't an option, because they don't support the chrome.tabs API.

**What I want to do:** inject the CSS without ANY user interaction. Because to inject the CSS I have to click on the icon to open the popup to load the js to load the css.

**How can I load that javascript file in the background to inject the css without ANY user interaction?**

Comment: _As I have mentioned in previous questions_??? StackOverflow isn't your blog...

Comment: @Jacques, This question is almost at the point that it's clear. However, you're missing one part: **How** should the CSS be injected? When the tab is navigating to a certain URL? When the user interacts with some browser control? ..?

Comment: Question is very unclear. Rephrase it or restructure it please.

Comment: I have edited my question. Just to remind you again, the CSS needs to be injected without any user interaction, AUTOMATICALLY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have [answered earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9342372/938089?chrome-extension-load-a-backgorund-js-each-time-the-page-reloads), you can inject CSS via a Content script definition in `manifest.json`. Your content script can [communicate](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#content%20script) with the background page using [`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-sendRequest) (in the content script) and [`chrome.extension.onRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest) (at the background page).

So, content scripts **are** the way to solve your problem.

Examples:

- [Invoking a Google Chrome extension from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597310/invoking-a-google-chrome-extension-from-javascript)
- [Cross-domain XMLHttpRequest using background pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699615/cross-domain-xmlhttprequest-using-background-pages/7699773#7699773)

Comment: This page, http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html says: "However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot
Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)"           So how do I use chrome.extension.sendRequest on the content script?

Comment: @JacquesBlom Have you read the [linked documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#content%20scripts) and examples in the linked answers? I provided them for a reason...

Comment: Would you please mind giving me an example or explain what I should do. Do I have to do the XMLHttpRequest on the background page and then inject the css with the content script. If so, how do I inject the css, because I can't use chrome.tabs.insertCSS. Thanks so much!

Comment: It isn't working. The code in the sendRequest function won't execute. I addrd an alert, but to no avail. An alert works with the onRequest function though.

Comment: `chrome.extension.onRequest` should be `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener`. See http://pastebin.com/yXEdA6cu

Comment: Here is my plugin's code: http://pastebin.com/0YEjHPUD. The 001.css is in the same folder. It won't work. Would you mind telling me what exactly is wrong?

Comment: This code didn't work. Even outside the sendRequest function.      `var currentid = '001.css';
var style = document.createElement('link');
style.type = "text/css";
style.rel = "stylesheet";
style.href = currentid;
(document.head||document.documentElement.firstElementChild).appendChild(style); `

Comment: @JacquesBlom What's the response text of [`http://localhost:8888/login/popuplogin/myaccount.php`](http://localhost:8888/login/popuplogin/myaccount.php)? If `001.css` is contained within your extension's directory, use the `chrome.extension.getURL` method: http://pastebin.com/aRwMA4fS

Comment: The response text is: `Pink,001,pink|Orange,002,orange|L!ime,003,lime|||||001`

Comment: @JacquesBlom Where's `001.css` located? If it's at your external server, you have to specify the absolute URI: `var currentid = 'http://localhost:8888/login/popuplogin/' + currenttheme + '.css';`. See http://pastebin.com/By6iAsnF

Comment: It is in the plugin folder itself, for now.

Comment: The code you provided won't work. :( The website's CSS is still the same.

Comment: Use the developer tools to check if the requested file exist. The code will only fail if the style declarations are overridden by the page's style, or when the path is not found (if you want any more help, specify the locations of your script, CSS and page).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, "specify the locations of your script, CSS and page"

Comment: "Where are your script and CSS files located? What's the URL of the page in which you're ibjecting the CSS?"

Comment: Oh, thanks! **My CSS file:** it is located in the root of the plugin directory (where manifest.json is) **My script:** Is also located in the root of the directory (called contentscript.js) **The URL i'm injecting the CSS to** is Facebook.com. You can access them all at: http://pastebin.com/0YEjHPUD

Comment: @JacquesBlom Then use the **[`chrome.extension.getURL`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL)** method, as mentioned in my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348728/execute-js-to-change-css-in-background-chrome-extensions/9350056#comment11846759_9350056). See http://pastebin.com/aRwMA4fS

Comment: I tried that, but it won't work. The only thing that worked so far was when I used chrome.tabs.insertCSS in a js file attached to the popup.html.

Comment: @JacquesBlom I have successfully tested my snippet in an isolated extension. The CSS is successfully injected. What exactely doesn't work? Add `!important` after your rules, eg `background-color: red !important;` to make sure that the styles are applied. **Test this extension to see that my snippet works fine: http://pastebin.com/85BiPde7**

Comment: Thanks! It works brilliantly! My plugins are now finished. I really appreciate what you have done for me.

Comment: @JacquesBlom If your problem has been solved, mark the answer as accepted, so that others can see how to solve the question.