# Chrome extension is not loading on web sites with https

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We developed a Chrome extension and it is working fine for websites with out https protocol. But, it is not loading on sites running with https protocol.

Are there any work around to fix this issue?

Comment: Could you provide more information? What's in your manifest (especially permissions/content script match patterns)? How it doesn't load?

Comment: Here are the chrome manifest information.  "permissions": [
      "cookies",
      "tabs",
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*",
      "contextMenus",
      "webRequest"     
  ], "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "css": ["css/ext/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css", "css/ext/jquery.jscrollpane.css","css/ext/jquery.alerts.css" ],   
      "js": ["js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js", "js/ext/cycle.js", "js/ext/jquery.alerts.js", "js/ext/jquery.carouFredSel-6.1.0-packed.js", "js/ext/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js", "js/ext/jquery.jscrollpane.js"],      
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }

Comment: The manifest looks fine. How it doesn't load and what does your extension do?

Comment: We are injecting the CSS as per the approach mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619095/how-to-inject-css-into-webpage-through-chrome-extension (Look at the last answer). With this approach, we are unable to inject CSS into HTTPS sites?

Comment: Edit your question with new information instead of putting it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, the `matches` in `content_scripts` should be like this:

```json
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/",
            "https://*/"
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: When you want to work on all url, you should set `matches` to `["<all_urls>"]`