# How to set that everywhere cursor style = pointer to my own url

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I build an extension to Google Chrome that changes the cursor and every time I go over a tag that have style cursor: pointer i'm change the cursor I currently take and check every tag with the cursor is a pointer if it true I change it but I do not want  every time the page refreshes to loop all the tags it is not Effective Is there a way to determine that every tag that have style cursor: pointer, pointer going to be something that i declared

Comment: "pointer is written"? do you mean a listener to every time the user point the cursor ? . It depends how your app build .. if you have wrap page as index.html you can put the code there maybe(to prevent loading on navigate etc.) and what about to use `CSS` instead JS?

Answer (score 0):

Inject a style CSS to override all tags from `cursor: pointer;` to `cursor: initial;`

Comment: How about showing how? I tried and failed

Comment: i will be happy if you can show how

Comment: @NetanelNikitaSto Please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619095/how-to-inject-css-into-webpage-through-chrome-extension